# Virtualbox Installation Issues due to Missing Kernel Modules

Tags: virtualbox, installation, kernel-modules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to Install VirtualBox Due to Missing Kernel Module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-due-to-missing-kernel-module)

I have dual systems: Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed on my machine. Now I would like to install virtualbox under Ubuntu.

When i do `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose`, there is an error:

```
Setting up virtualbox-ose (4.0.4-dfsg-1ubuntu4) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                           
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox-ose, action "restart" failed.
```

then launching virtualbox in a terminal, I got this warning:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Then I did "sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-dkms" and "sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic", they all told me that the package is already the newest version.

To fix the kernel module issue, it seems that i have to install kernel-devel. But i got a problem:

`root@ubuntu# yum install kernel-devel

Setting up Install Process

No package kernel-devel available.

Nothing to do`

Then i am stuck...

Could anyone help me to get rid of this warning, and also get the kernel module loaded?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try rebooting the machine.

Comment: The duplicate is also a question from this user. Please answer there as he has posted extra information and there is already one answer.