# Unable to Install VirtualBox Due to Missing Kernel Module

Tags: 11.04, virtualbox, kernel-modules, pae

I am trying to install VirtualBox on my Ubuntu.

I first tried to `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose` in a terminal, but after the configuration step, it fails with [an error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49052/the-character-device-dev-vboxdrv-does-not-exist):

> No suitable module for running kernel found
>   When proceeding with starting `virtualbox`, I get this error:
>   WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
>      Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
>      headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

So I tried the package from http://www.virtualbox.org/, but starting VirtualBox fails with:

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
>      available for the current kernel (2.6.38-8-generic-pae) or it failed to
>      load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
>   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
> ```
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

So I ran `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`, but it fails too:

```
* Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                           [ OK ] 
* Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                                                            [ OK ] 
* Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                                                       
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.38-8-generic-pae cannot be found at
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic-pae/build or /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic-pae/source.

* Failed, trying without DKMS
* Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                             
* Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong
```

[The contents of `/var/log/vbox-install.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/627992/).

As I am stuck, I also tried to install `kernel-devel` with `yum`, still fruitless:

```
root@ubuntu# yum install kernel-devel
Setting up Install Process
No package kernel-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

Now I've no idea how to correct this. Any ideas?

Comment: `yum`? are you using ubuntu? who says you need `kernel-devel`?

Comment: Pffft, install Virtualbox from the repositories.

Comment: I am still stuck on Yum :(

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/var/log/kern.log` on http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the link here?

Comment: @Lekensteyn do you need `/var/log/kern.log` after executing which commands?

Comment: No, old entries are visible too.

Comment: @Lekensteyn here it is [/var/log/kern.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/628004/)

Comment: I had a similar problem. I already had virtual box 4.1.4 installed but when I updated my ubuntu kernel to 2.6.35-30-generic-pae, it stopped working. I'm kind of surprised that when I updated the kernel the headers weren't updated as well. I solved the problem by running sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.35-30-generic-pae and then sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doing everything as root by using `su` and the `yum` package manager is something that fits for Redhat-based distros, but not Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, you run command as root by prefixing commands with `sudo`. The package manager used by Ubuntu is apt.

To install VirtualBox, run:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose
```

This will take care of dependencies like the kernel headers which is included in the package `linux-headers-generic`. If you've a PAE kernel, you need to install the headers first (in your case `linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae`), which can be done with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

`uname -r` gives the loaded kernel version and saved you from manually entering the kernel version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I tried this approach in the first place, but got some problem, could you please take a look?http://askubuntu.com/questions/49052/the-character-device-dev-vboxdrv-does-not-exist

Comment: `virtualbox-4.0` is not in the default repositories. Do you've a 3rd-party PPA installed? Remove that PPA or package and install `virtualbox-ose`.

Comment: @SoftTimur you should NOT post duplicate questions, if they're related to the same problem, they could get flagged as such.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your reply, I have edited the 2 questions which are linked... hope there will be a solution...

Comment: @SoftTimur: do not forget to purge virtualbox before (`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.0 virtualbox-ose`)

Comment: Indeed, I could install `virtualbox-ose` well after installing `linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae`, thank you very much, @Lekensteyn

Comment: This did work for me, though I had to also run `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` to actually boot.

Comment: I think the installation order is important, without the headers, the kernel module build fails. After installing, the module is available, but not immediately loaded. So after a reboot (or with `modprobe`), it should be loaded. That's what I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I had the `linux-headers-<version>-generic-pae` installed but was ironically missing the `linux-headers-generic-pae`. If you install those that should help maybe.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Install *build-essentials*.

```
apt-get install build-essentials
```

and install *linux-kernel-headers*

```
apt-get install linux-kernel-headers
```

or

```
apt-get install linux-kernel-*
```

Install *dkms*

```
apt-get install dkms
```

Comment: sorry for the wrong indentation .. 
apt-get install build-essential linux-kernel-* dkms

Comment: There is no such package as `build-essentials`, it's `build-essential`. `linux-kernel-*` packages do not exist, it's named `linux-headers-...-generic` where `...` is the kernel version.