# Problem with VirtualBox after enabling 'pae' in 10.04 kernel

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, pae

I installed the `2.6.32-32-generic-pae` kernel over my existing `2.6.32-32-generic` kernel.

This solved the problem I had with the system not showing the full amount of RAM, but it has had a side-effect.  I can't start my VirtualBox VMs.  I get this message:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>   Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and execute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root

`virtualbox-ose-dkms` was already installed and when I ran `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`, I got another error message:

> FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.

I purged *virtualbox-ose-dkms* (complete removal) and then re-installed it, but I still got the same error.

I then repeated the full re-installation, but this time with the **previous** *non-pae* kernel. It **works**, but fails when I reboot into the *pae* kernel.

Next I uninstalled and then re-installed VirtualBox into the *pae* system, but it gave the same error.

What can I do to get VirtualBox running with the *pae* kernel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Install VirtualBox Due to Missing Kernel Module](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-due-to-missing-kernel-module)

Comment: I've treid the suggeston in the above-mentioned *possible* duplicate... I purged *linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic* and installed *linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae* .. I still get the error.

Comment: You need to install the headers matching your kernel version. See [the updated answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-due-to-missing-kernel-module/49065#49065).

Comment: I never had issues when installing Virtual Box from the repository maintained by Oracle: [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487)

Comment: I got it!.. thanks... I think I was installing things in the wrong order... This worked for me... After purging, I installed in this order: `sudo apt-get install  linux-headers-2.6.32-32-generic-pae`,then `sudo apt-get install  virtualbox-ose`,  (The reverse order didn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was solved thanks to the comments to the question... VirtualBox is working again... by uninstalling and re-installing things in the correct sequence..  (I've "answered" in this way, as there was no other *specific* answer...)