# Virtual Box won't load

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, compiling, additional-drivers

I am unable to get Virtual Box to load since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10.  It tells me to rebuild the kernel modules by running `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`. When I do in terminal the system cannot find the linux-headers-3.2.0-32-generic.  I checked `/usr/src` and the only headers there are for versions **3.5.0-17** and **3.5.0-18**.

Can anyone please tell me how to recreate the headers that the system is looking for?

Comment: How did you install virtualbox? Did you download it from the website or did you install it using `apt-get` ?

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-due-to-missing-kernel-module

Comment: I downloaded un update and installed using the package installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install linux headers, remove virtualbox-dkms and install virtualbox-dkms. The step by step instructions are given in the following link,
http://xchamitha.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/fixing-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-1210.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, due to kernel version I guess you have Ubuntu 12.10 (12.11 is not a version of Ubuntu, please edit your question and correct it).

Then you said that virtualbox not work due to missing headers of 3.2.0-32 kernel. This kernel is from 12.04 Ubuntu version . Ubuntu 12.10 uses 3.5.0-17 (3.5 series). 
So the only thing I can guess is that you've upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and the old kernel remained to your system.

The easy solution here is to remove the old kernel 3.2.0-32.

[See here on how to remove the old kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Then run again `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advice of @NikTh but that made my system unable to boot.  It appears that the Grub boot loader did not completely upgrade when I upgraded Ubuntu to Version 12.10.  The package was extracted but not installed.  I was able to determine this fact after making a command line boot to kernel 3.5.0-18.  I then rebooted from my original installation CD of version 9.04 and from the menu chose "Recover a broken system".  Then at the rescue-mode chooser I selected "Reinstall GRUB boot loader".  This solved my problem by correcting the errors in the boot loader and therefore providing pointers to the current kernel for vbox to function again.